# Devel Module bogus output

Tags: theming, debugging

I need help with the devel module. I'm outputting my objects/variables with `dpm($variables);` into my template.php and I get the same output on every page. It's pulling one of my views and showing it as the markup for every page. I'm running Drupal 7 with my own subtheme of the Omega project. Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

What preprocess function or theme function override are you putting `dpm()` inside of? If you are inside of hook_preprocess_views_view() then I would expect that you'd get the same results in on every page that the given view is on.